# check if list element exists in an R list

Tags: r

I have a list "ans" here are its few entries

```
[[93]]
[1] "<dd>male, 31 years old</dd>" "black male"                       
[3] "31"                               

[[94]]
character(0)

[[95]]
[1] "<dd>female, 23 years old</dd>" "female"                       
[3] "23"                               

[[96]]
[1] "<dd>male, 23 years old</dd>" "male"                       
[3] "23"
```

I have to find if each entries matches a certain age

so I have a loop like this

```
for(item in ans){
    if(item[3] && item[3]==age){
         count = count + 1
    }
}
```

but their are some entries like

```
[[94]]
    character(0)
```

due to which I am getting a error `: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

how do I get rid of this problem

Comment: Your data doesn't look like a data.frame.

Comment: Please use `dput` to give a sample of your data. If you want to use a `for` loop (not my first choice), you could test if `length(item) >= 3`.

Comment: Try `as.integer(item[3])==age`. Your data seems to be stored as strings and not integer/numeric. For your error, you can add an if condition to check whether that entry is even populated, and if that returns TRUE only then should you check the age.

Comment: @Codoremifa: I don't think you have understood the problem correctly: `"42" ==42 #[1] TRUE`

Comment: This looks like homework from the Coursera class [Computing for Data Analysis](https://www.coursera.org/course/compdata). I suggest you read the [guidelines linked here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @DWin, I didn't know `"42" == 42` returns TRUE, and I find it strange. I read the help entry and see how R does it ("...two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other...") but I don't really see the need to do it. Is it just R compensating for a user goofing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me:

```
ans <- list(c("<dd>male, 31 years old</dd>", "black male", "31"  ), character(0))
count <- 0
age <- "31"
for(item in ans){
  if (isTRUE(item[3] == age)) {
    count <- count + 1
  }
}
count
```

Is this what you want?